# I forwarded my domain at IONOS to my github webpage. But example.com/defaultsite still goes to IONOS template web page. How can I prevent this?

Tags: redirects

I have a domain purchased from IONOS, call it example.com.
I have set it to "HTTP redirect" to example.github.io.
However, when I google the name of my website, google finds example.com/defaultsite which goes to a default webpage by IONOS. How can I prevent this? I want to remove the /defaultsite subdirectory so that when the name is googled it goes to my website directly.

Comment: When did you do that?  It can take a day or so.  Also you need to flush the browser cache.

Comment: I did it quite a while ago (months). Note that entering example.com works fine, but google finds example.com/defaultsite which leads to a template web page.

Comment: Did the answer work for you ?

Comment: My guess is that you don't actually want to use redirects at all. You should use dns `A` and `CNAME` records to assign the domain to your site and adjust your GitHub configuration for a custom domain

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't want that page anymore, ensure that you raise a 404 for it on your new site.
2. Make sure that when you type that link in the browser, it goes to your new site.
3. You can tell Google to re-index that page

   - Go to Google Search Console
   - Select the domain in the dropdown othe n top left (if you have more than one)
   - Click on URL Inspection
   - Type in the URL
   - Click on **Request Indexing**

Comment: Is this posted to the correct question?  This answer doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question asked here.